# WPF - Tooltip content binded to a combobox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid which has, in the head of every column a combobox. I want a tooltip to appear when hovering the combobox, to show the selected item value

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" Name="griglia" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Test}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <ComboBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SingleSelectionComboBoxItem}" DisplayMemberPath="Oggetto" Width="100" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.Selezione, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  SelectionChanged="SingleSelectionComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ToolTip Content = "what should i put here????"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

What should i put inside the content property of the tooltip? I already tried

```
Content = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}},Path=DataContext.Tot.Oggetto}"
```

where `Tot.Oggetto` is a string containing the displayed item in the combobox but it doesn't work

EDIT: I tried already to set tooltip property fo the combobox like

```
ToolTip="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

but it does not show any tooltip

Comment: Try setting the placement target combined with your binding.
https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/08/30/375-binding-something-in-a-tooltip-to-a-property-on-the-parent-control/

You need to do this becaues ToolTip is a popup and has a different visual tree and cannot find ancestors without some assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first try is setting the Tooltip of the DataGridColumnHeader, but it seems you want to set the Tooltip of the ComboBox, right?

You can set the Tooltip of a ComboBox to show its selected value as follows:

```
<ComboBox ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedValue}" ...>
```

`RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` is binding to the ComboBox itself. Then `Path=SelectedValue` specifies that you want to bind to the property SelectedValue of this ComboBox, instead of binding directly to itself.

So your code would then be: (I erased the code that was setting the Tooltip of the DataGridColumnHeader and modified the code for the ComboBox inside the DataTemplate)

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" Name="griglia" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Test}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <ComboBox ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedValue}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SingleSelectionComboBoxItem}" DisplayMemberPath="Oggetto" Width="100" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.Selezione, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  SelectionChanged="SingleSelectionComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. I just needed to specify the property of the SelectedValue to display since this is an instance of a class

Comment: You are right. You need to set the SelectedValuePath to be SelectedValuePath="Ogetto".